# Group by and take count of first occurrence Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

A pandas dataframe has 2 columns.

| Number | Character |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | b |
| 111 | b |
| 111 | c |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | a |
| 222 | c |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | a |
| 222 | c |
| 333 | c |
| 333 | a |
| 333 | a |
| 333 | b |
| 333 | c |
| 333 | c |

Now I want to find for each number group first Character column value count.

Desired Output

| Number | Character | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | a | 2 |
| 222 | b | 2 |
| 333 | c | 3 |

so we need group by on Number and need first value in Character column count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first filter only first values by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) comparing by original values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then count values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Number')['Character'].transform('first').eq(df['Character'])]

df = df.groupby(['Number','Character']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)    
   Number Character  count
0     111         a      2
1     222         b      2
2     333         c      3
```